# How to verify column data for all the rows in the table in protractor

Tags: html, protractor

I'm trying to use below code to verify data for one particular column for all the rows.

Below is my code I have used:

```
 var mytable = element(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-12']/table/tbody"));
 let rows_table: any = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
 console.log("rows_table"+rows_table);
 browser.sleep(10000);
 let rows_count: any = rows_table.size();

 for (var row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
    var Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    var columns_count = Columns_row.size();
    console.log("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
    for (var column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
         var celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
         console.log("Cell Value of row number " + row + " and column number 
         " + column + " Is " + celtext);`
```

But its not working.

Comment: How is it not working? do you get an error?

Comment: Its not showing any error basically.In console its passing the test case but not giving the output. For console parts also, its not printing anything in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath to find all td of one column directly.

```
var util = require('util'); // it's nodejs build-in module
var expect= require('chai').expect;

function readColumn(columnName) {
    let columnIndexes = {
        'columnA': 0,
        'columnB': 1
    };

    let columnIndex = columnIndexes[columnName];

    let xpath = util.format(
       "//div[@class='col-sm-12']/table/tbody/tr/td[%s]",
        ++columnIndex);

    return element.all(by.xpath(xpath)).getText();
}

let expectValues = ['Car', 'Cat'];

readColumn('columnA').then(function(values) {
    // use Chai do assertion
    expect(values).to.deep.equal(expectValues)
});
```

Comment: In this line, expect(values).to.deep.equal(expectValues), '.to' is showing error.How to resolve? Also, would you please explain column Indexes?

Comment: @Shruti, please  get the key points from my code, do assertion is not the key point to resolve your problem, If you use Jasmine, please change the assertion to Jasmine style, I use `Chai` in my code.